# How to make django model choice field human readable

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

So I have django model choice field with months

```
class EntrySummary(models.Model):

    JANUARY = '1'
    FEBRUARY = '2'
    MARCH = '3'
    APRIL = '4'
    MAY = '5'
    JUNE = '6'
    JULY = '7'
    AUGUST = '8'
    SEPTEMBER = '9'
    OCTOBER = '10'
    NOVEMBER = '11'
    DECEMBER = '12'

    MONTH_CHOICES = (
        (JANUARY, 'January'),
        (FEBRUARY, 'February'),
        (MARCH, 'March'),
        (APRIL, 'April'),
        (MAY, 'May'),
        (JUNE, 'June'),
        (JULY, 'July'),
        (AUGUST, 'August'),
        (SEPTEMBER, 'September'),
        (OCTOBER, 'October'),
        (NOVEMBER, 'November'),
        (DECEMBER, 'December'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255
    )
    month = models.CharField(
       max_length=2,
       choices = MONTH_CHOICES,
       default=JANUARY,
    )
```

Views.py
I render it

```
def based_onmonth(request, *args, **kwargs):
    monthId = request.GET.get('month')
    monthEntry = EntrySummary.objects.filter(month=monthId)
    return render(request, 'app/js_templates/month_dropdown_list.html', {'MonthItem': monthId})
```

html template:

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for item in MonthItem %}
    <p>item.name</p>
<option value="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Doing this i receive  {'month': '2'} in my select section

My question is how to print just 2 without month

Comment: You are sending back the `monthId` you got from request.GET in your views. then you for loop it?! something doesnt look right here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `get_<field_name>_display` mechanism:

```
# Return the right thing from your view.
return render(request, 'app/js_templates/month_dropdown_list.html', {'MonthItem': monthEntry})
```

and in your template:

```
{% for item in MonthItem %}
    <option value="{{ item.month }}">{{ item.get_month_display }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Comment: {{ month.get_name_display }} display empty space, without any text.

Comment: If the answer was of any help, please remember to upvote or select it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your return you will want to send the `monthEntry` to the frontend:

```
return render(request, 'app/js_templates/month_dropdown_list.html', {'MonthItem': monthEntry})
```